# Sending data from the web server to a mobile device

Tags: android, ios, http, mobile, push-notification

maybe you can help me with the following problem:
I have an application installed on the mobile device ( native on iOS, Android, WP ).
I need to send a short message from the web server ( possibly, hosted on AWS ) to some specific mobile device. The message should arrive as quickly as possible ( 1 second is already too much ).

Maybe you can suggest something to me?
At the moment I am thinking about following options:
1) Make a long-held http request from the device to a server ( as far as I remember this is also called long-polling approach ). I am very concerned with the battery life while using this approach.
2) Push notifications ( like GCM for Android ). I haven't worked with them, but I did some research in the internet. How fast is it?? If I send it from the server, will it arrive during some seconds? Can I use push notification to send data to my mobile application. ( or it's just for marketing purpose to show a message on the screen )
3) Make a web server on the mobile application device. Does the mobile have an ip address? Is it possible to connect to this mobile device? How often does ip address change?

Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that making a web server on android is not an option.
Because it's not accessible from the external internet, just from local network.

Comment: Yes you're right, it will only be available in the network till the router

Comment: I like this question. I have the same problem. I'm creating a doorbell app which needs to alert my Android phone... somehow. Maybe my iPad too.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know,

**1) Make a long-held http request from the device to a server**

Does that mean that you want to make an HTTP request each seconds ? If that's so, you can be concerned about the battery life...

**2) Push notifications**

Notification come quiet quickly but I think there is no certitude about how long it takes. I noticed one time that it took up to 10 minutes, in the other cases it was a few seconds.
This is not for marketing purpose only. You send characterS that can be plain text or json/xms text ....

**3) Make a web server on the mobile application device.**

This is possible.

I made one by using **Jetty** library but I don't understand how you will get data from internet if its not by making HTTP request.

Comment: Long-held http request - same as long-lasting http request.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)
So the request just stays, server doesn't close the connection.